# Jenkins (formerly Hudson) keeps writing to catalina.out despite log configuration

Tags: logging, hudson, tomcat6, jenkins

Hy there

I have the problem that [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) keeps writing to the catalina.out which keeps filling the disk, where Jenkins is installed.

This is what I tried so far:

1. I tried to overwrite the log levels for '' (default) as well as for  '`org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]`' and set them to '`WARNING`'. However, when I reload jenkins in the tomcat (6.0.28) manager interface the '' (default) - entry is gone and the other one is reset to '`FINE`'
2. In the tomcat Context.xml I changed `<Context>` to `<Context swallowOutput="true">` which should prevent Jenkins of writing to the standard out. I guess the swallowOutput attribute would have to be inside the jenkins.war in order to work correctly.

I don't see why the standard log configuration of Jenkins has to be this verbose and I am seriously wondering how I can change the log level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much

Comment: Pretty sure this is an open issue http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7235

Comment: not sure if is the same problem I have... my jenkins is not logging 20MB at startup, but about 3GB/day all over its execution... at one point I have to stop tomcat, delete catalina.out and hope for the best...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to configure log4j in tomcat 6 (it's different in other versions):
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

Note that this will **not** help if your executors are writing to disk.  Those use a separate java process from tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The updated jenkins issue is available on this URL:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7235
We've exactly the same problem, but no solution for the moment.